# Class with different types

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, vector

I am working on a C++ ROS Project, which contains different classes, each containing a vector.

The difficulty is that the vectors can be of different types. For example:

```
class A{
    public
        .....
    private 
        std::vector<Class_C> List
}
class B{
    public  
        .....
    private 
        std::vector<Class_D> List
}
```

How could I achieve such task? I would like to find a way to simplify my code using templates, inheritances, and other language features.

Comment: Question not clear

Comment: What are you going to do with the lists? What is the purpose of all the other classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I cannot comment because of my reputation I have to write an answer, but [Gill Bates' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36015161/5248907) could solve your issue even though *you are not clear on what you want to accomplish*. And to extend on his answer you could use inheritance based of his template class to ease your coding and force a type into your list (you would also need to change your list visibility to protected in this case):

```
class FooInt : public A<int>{
    public
        void print() { /* print List's content */ }
...
};

class FooString : public A<std::string>{
    public
        void print() { /* print List's content */ }
...
};
```

You use your classes this way:

```
FooInt hello;
hello.print(); // Would print list of int

FooString moto;
moto.print(); // Would print list of string
```

Note that the classes' names are written as Foo* only to help you understand that their underlying lists would contain the types written in the names, this could be your class B inheriting from the class A...

Answer (score 3):

Just use a template argument:

```
template <typename T>
class A{
    public
        .....
    private 
        std::vector<T> List;
}
```

This allows `A` to have a `vector` of any type:

```
A<Class_C> foo;
A<Class_D> bar;
```

Comment: And if I want a B class which inherit from A, is it possible to lock the type ? if the B class can only have "Class_C" as typename for example

Comment: @S.Perfees Perhaps you should rethink what you are doing. ["Composition over inheritance"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    public:
        .....
    protected: 
        std::vector<T> List;
};

class B : public A<Class_D> {
    public:
    .....
};

B b;
```